# MySQL generating monthly report for each day, counting 0 for null rows

Tags: mysql

Consider the following table

```
id | sell_count | created_at
```

Suppose I want to generate a report in MySQL by date of a given month. When an admin selects a month and year and hits get report button, I want to show them a monthly report from day 1 to day 31, group by date.

Suppose the table has no data for date 15th March. So it will not be visible in the result set as `date: 2018-03-15 , sell_count: 0`. Is it possible/better ways to include that specific date into the result set in MySQL? Currently I'm doing it in PHP.

Comment: Do you have a calendar/dates table in your db?

Comment: Nope. I dont have any

Comment: Pity, sql is rubbish at generating dates on the fly. I would stick with what you have.